# Google Analytics API Quota Suddenly Decreased

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

My company's product depends on the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/), and our quota was suddenly drastically reduced.  Does anybody know who to contact at Google to get this fixed quickly?  I've re-submitted our application for a higher [quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas), but if this does not get resolved ASAP, I'm going to have a bunch of angry customers.

Comment: If someone went into your project on Dev console and turned on and off the Google Analytics API it will reset the quota to the default, removing any increase you previously where granted.   (Just a guess you are going to have to wait for them to re-increase you again)

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo.  That's what Google told me.  Funny thing is that nobody thinks they did that.  But, I guess it could have happened by accident.

Comment: Perhaps you can use several Google accounts in the Google API console and share several API keys to get it under quota?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone went into your project on [Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) and turned on and off the Google Analytics API it will reset the quota to the default, removing any increase you previously where granted. (Just a guess you are going to have to wait for them to re-increase you again)

Side note I should send in a feature request:  It should either not reset it or it should pop up asking if you really really really want to turn it on and off.